# Is Kant's postulate of the existence of God a metaethical assumption?

Tags: metaphysics, reference-request, kant, existence, metaethics

Also, I would like to get some bibliographical reference about Kantian metaethics.

Comment: For an initial biblio, you can see [Kant's Moral Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kant-moral/) as well as [Kant's Ethics](https://www.iep.utm.edu/kantmeta/#H8).